# Silex: routing variable assignment issue

Tags: php, request, silex, forwarding

I recently wrote a post about [request forwarding in Silex](https://coderwall.com/p/wmlx8g), which used a blog example to explain sub requests in Silex.

I use a slightly modified version of this example for a domain controller.
The path to the domain endpoint = /product/domain

A domain can also have a webhosting package attached to it.
The url path for this endpoint would be /product/domain/(id)/webhosting/

You can fetch info about a webhosting package by using the url path.
The url path for this endpoint would be /product/domain/(id)/webhosting/(id)

To handle these sub requests, I have a method called forwardRequest, which has no parameters in it's method signature, but uses func_get_args to keep it dynamic.

Unfortunately this doesn't work as Silex uses the named parameters in your route to call your method. So if you have /product/domain/domain_id/webhosting/webhosting_id, your method should have a signature of method($domain_id, $webhosting_id), which is a PITA if you want to forward multiple endpoints through one method. If you have additional /product/domain/domain_id/emailhosting and /product/domain/domain_id/dns endpoints, you have to create a method for each in order to forward the request.

Does anyone have a solution in which I can use only 1 method to forward all these sub requests?

Note: I'm using PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of silex that decides which arguments to pass to the controller is called the "controller resolver". The default controller resolver uses reflection. You can override the `controller_resolver` service with a custom implementation though.

Defining a custom controller resolver that wraps the existing one but replaces the arguments with a single one, the request:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolverInterface;

class RequestArgumentControllerResolver implements ControllerResolverInterface
{
    protected $resolver;

    public function __construct(ControllerResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $this->resolver = $resolver;
    }

    public function getController(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->resolver->getController($request, $controller);
    }

    public function getArguments(Request $request, $controller)
    {
        return [$request];
    }
}
```

Extend the existing controller resolver with the newly defined decorator:

```
$app['controller_resolver'] = $app->share($app->extend('controller_resolver', function ($resolver, $app) {
    return new RequestArgumentControllerResolver($resolver);
}));
```

Note: This is just one way of doing it. You don't have to decorate, you can also replace the resolver completely if you like. And obviously this is just a very basic example of only passing a single arg to the controller, you can do something more sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks, this example pointed me in the right direction and helped solve my problem.